# After first successful query to heroku postgres table, every query after fails

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, heroku-postgres

This is a server-side web application (Node.js and Express) deployed to Heroku. I'm using the [Heroku Postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) add-on (`client` refers to connection to my Heroku Postgres database).

I structured my promise using [this](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries) as a reference.

The first GET request is successful and returns result of `client.query('SELECT * FROM passenger WHERE username = $1;', [username])`. The second GET request receives an Internal Server Error and every GET Request after receives the same error. I don't know where to begin looking for what's causing the issue? I'm not sure why it would work once and then fail the same GET request right after.

JS script

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var validator = require('validator')
var { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const router = express.Router()
const data = require('./app.json')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

var cors = require('cors')
var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

var connectionString = *censored*;
var { Client } = require('pg')
var client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL || connectionString,
    ssl:{
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
})
client.connect()

app.use('/', router)

router.get('/passenger.json', cors(corsOptions), check('username'), (req, res) => {
    var errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty() ||  Object.keys(req.query).length === 0){
        res.json([])
    }

    var username = req.query.username
    username = validator.escape(username)

    client
        .query('SELECT * FROM passenger WHERE username = $1;', [username])
        .then(result => res.json(result.rows))
        .catch(e => res.sendStatus(500))
        .then(() => client.end())
})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

GET Request attempts:

```sh
% curl -X GET "https://agile-dusk-02160.herokuapp.com/passenger.json?username=xIHNcana"
[{"username":"xIHNcana","lat":42.385408,"lng":-71.08689919999999},{"username":"xIHNcana","lat":42.385408,"lng":-71.08689919999999},{"username":"xIHNcana","lat":42.385408,"lng":-71.08689919999999},{"username":"xIHNcana","lat":42.385408,"lng":-71.08689919999999}]%                                         
% curl -X GET "https://agile-dusk-02160.herokuapp.com/passenger.json?username=xIHNcana"
Internal Server Error%
```

Heroku logs that reference the two GET requests:

```
2020-06-24T22:25:14.123304+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/passenger.json?username=xIHNcana" host=agile-dusk-02160.herokuapp.com request_id=07eca9c7-aaa2-45fd-a32c-55fe0551e4f6 fwd="73.126.3.226" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=502 protocol=https
2020-06-24T22:25:15.520949+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/passenger.json?username=xIHNcana" host=agile-dusk-02160.herokuapp.com request_id=28c34b65-c9cf-439f-901d-51ae220e90bf fwd="73.126.3.226" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=500 bytes=273 protocol=https
```

This is what the heroku postgres table looks like:

```sh
agile-????-?????::DATABASE=> select * from passenger;
 username |    lat    |        lng         
----------+-----------+--------------------
 xIHNcana | 42.385408 | -71.08689919999999
 USERNAME |     12.12 |              12.12
 xIHNcana | 42.385408 | -71.08689919999999
 USERNAME |     12.12 |              12.12
 xIHNcana | 42.385408 | -71.08689919999999
 USERNAME |     12.12 |              12.12
 xIHNcana | 42.385408 | -71.08689919999999
 USERNAME |     12.12 |              12.12
(8 rows)
```

Comment: Check the Postgres logs. I'm betting that a transaction failed and needs to be rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from `Client` (single client connection) to `Pool` (connection pooling) via the `pg-pool` module and it's working now. From [here](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling), node-postgres notes using a connection pool is best for a web app that handles frequent queries. I think these were the issues with my first attempt:

- PostgreSQL server can only handle [a limited number of clients at a time](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections). Depending on the available memory of your PostgreSQL server you may even crash the server if you connect an unbounded number of clients.
- PostgreSQL can only process one query at a time on a single connected client in a first-in first-out manner. If your multi-tenant web app is using only a single connected client all queries among all simultaneous requests will be pipelined and executed serially, one after the other. No Good!

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var validator = require('validator')
var { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const router = express.Router()
const data = require('./app.json')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

var cors = require('cors')
var corsOptions = {
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}

var connectionString = *censored*;
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL || connectionString,
    ssl:{
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
})
pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
  console.error('Unexpected error on idle client', err)
  process.exit(-1)
})

router.get('/passenger.json', cors(corsOptions), check('username'), (req, res) => {
    var errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty() ||  Object.keys(req.query).length === 0){
        res.json([])
        return
    }

    var username = req.query.username
    username = validator.escape(username)

    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
      if (err) throw err
      client.query('SELECT * FROM passenger WHERE username = $1;', [username], (err, result) => {
        done()
        if (err) {
          res.sendStatus(500)
        } else {
          res.json(result.rows)
        }
      })
    })
})
```